# How to generate email even when expected attachment is missing?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

From browsing the internet I created an Excel file with a macro to send email to different addresses with different attachments to each email.

It works only if all files exist.
The file addresses are defined automatically and every month I send emails with 2 or 3 files attached but there are months that the file addresses don’t have a file, so the VBA doesn’t generate email.

I need that even if the file doesn’t exist, create email with the ones existing.

```vb
Sub send_email_with_multiple_attachments()
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Dim o As Outlook.Application
    Set o = New Outlook.Application
    Dim omail As Outlook.MailItem
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 2 To Range("c100").End(xlUp).Row
        Set omail = o.CreateItem(olMailltem)
        With omail
            .Body = "Caro cliente " & Cells(i, 2).Value
            .To = Cells(i, 3).Value
            .CC = Cells(i, 4).Value
            .Subject = Cells(i, 5).Value
            .Attachments.Add Cells(i, 6).Value
            .Attachments.Add Cells(i, 7).Value
            .Attachments.Add Cells(i, 8).Value
            .Attachments.Add Cells(i, 9).Value
            .Attachments.Add Cells(i, 10).Value
            .Display
        End With
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that if you put `On Error Resume Next` without error handling, this line hides **all** error messages until `End Sub` but the errors still occur, you just cannot see their messages. That means if you don't see your errors, you cannot fix them, if you don't fix them your code does not work. Remove that line and fix your errors or implement a complete error handling instead ([VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the contents of the cell before adding it as attachment.
Look at the code below, and review the code comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub send_email_with_multiple_attachments()

' section of all objects and parameters declaration
Dim o As Outlook.Application
Dim omail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strFileExists As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long

Set o = New Outlook.Application

For i = 2 To Range("c100").End(xlUp).Row
    Set omail = o.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With omail
        .Body = "Caro cliente " & Cells(i, 2).Value
        .To = Cells(i, 3).Value
        .CC = Cells(i, 4).Value
        .Subject = Cells(i, 5).Value

        ' add second loop to check all cells with possible attachments
        For j = 6 To 10
            ' make sure cells is not empty
            If (Cells(i, j).Value) <> "" Then
                strFileExists = Dir(Cells(i, j).Value) ' make sure file exits in current cell
                If strFileExists <> "" Then ' only if file exits add as attachment
                    .Attachments.Add Cells(i, j).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next j

        .Display
    End With
Next

End Sub
```